# Geometric proofs outside euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, big-list

I am looking for examples of geometric proofs of theorems in fields other than euclidean geometry.  The more surprising the fact that a geometric proof is possible, the better.  As two examples: 
-From Topics in the Theory of Numbers by Erdos, the proof that square root c is irrational if c is not a perfect square
-Isaac Barrow's proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: Also, I know this should probably be community wiki, but don't know how to make it one

Answer (score 1):

Here are images for a search for "proofs without words"

https://www.google.com/search?q=proofs+without+words&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6_tfxirjTAhVE5CYKHZpqCWUQ_AUICSgC&biw=960&bih=650

(I hope this link only answer is OK for community wiki.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a geometric (or at least, discrete-geometric) proof of 
[Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem),
$(p - 1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ for a prime $p$.

The proof uses regular polygons and star-shaped polygons.
See the [blog posting](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/GeometricWilson.shtml)
by Alexander Bogomolny.

Comment: This is very pretty!  Thanks